# How to edit columnheader values in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have separated my column headers and stored it in a separate matrix. The new matrix name is names and it has 2 rows with values r1,r2. When I try to change the value of `names(2,1)='r3'` it displays error stating that 'Conversion to cell from char is not possible'.

Is there any other way to assign new text value in matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `names{2,1}='r3'`. Your `names` variable is a cell array, and `r3` is a string, hence why your attempt didn't work. Using curly braces allows you to assign to the internal string of the cell.